# how to Check that a link is safe and trusted in PHP- YII?

Tags: php, mysql, security, iframe, yii2

I am developing a php web application through Yii2 framework that enable the user to enter any link and display it within iframe I need to know:

- is it safe for the web application and user to use this feature (iframe) with his own link
- how to avoid risks
- if the user has entered a link how to tell this link is safe and trusted
  thank,

Comment: display for them only or for all user ?

Comment: No, it's not safe. You could safelist a number of sites, and check every base url of the links provided to be in the safelist if you wanna let the user post them but that's still not safe since a possible security breach on the safelisted sites could lead to problems in your application too.

Comment: it will appear only  for the user who entered the link of iframe source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan it on virustotal.com / malwr.com or else. You could use this one with php https://github.com/jayzeng/virustotal_apiwrapper